# Calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} (\cot x)^{\sin x}$

Tags: limits

I have to calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} (\cot x)^{\sin x}$.

I'm trying calculating $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} e^{\sin x\ln{\cot x}}$

After using d'Hospital on $\frac{\sin x}{\frac{1}{\ln{\cot x}}}=\frac{0}{0}$ it doesnt help me at all...

Comment: Try L'Hopital on $$\frac{\log \cot x}{1/\sin x}$$.

Comment: If you are already familiar with the fact that $\lim_{u\to0}u^u=1$, then all you have to do is use the fact that $\cot x=\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}$.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

sin(x)*ln*cot(x) = sin(x)*ln*(cos(x)/sin(x)) = sin(x)*ln*(cos(x))-sin(x)*ln*(sin(x))

Now, sin(x)*ln*cos(x) goes to zero, and you can use L'Hopital's rule for the second term.

I hope that helps, and please excuse my bad  editing, this is my first time posting...

Comment: [$\LaTeX{}$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

This is of the form (infinity)^o .
So, it is equal to e^limit z tends to 0 ln(Sinz-1)cotz
The answer is e

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

Write $\cot(x)=\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$ and introduce an exponential-logarithm multiplication/cancellation:

\begin{equation*}
\exp (\lim_{x\to 0^+}\log(\frac{1}{\tan(x)})\sin(x))=\exp (\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log(\frac{1}{\tan(x)})}{\frac{1}{\sin(x)}}).
\end{equation*}

Apply L'Hopital's rule to get

\begin{equation*}
\exp(\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin^2(x)(1+\tan^2(x))}{\cos(x)\tan(x)}).
\end{equation*}

Try expressing $\tan$ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Can you finish from here?